# I'm closing recordset and dataconnection for my vba created pivot table, still they show up in existing connections

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm new in creating pivot tables in VBA. I'm curious to why my closed connections don't seem to affect existing connections? Also, I'm not able to refresh the table, I assume it is because VBA closes all connections when the procedure hits the end sub statement. 
How can I make my pivot table refreshable and why do the connections always apprear in the existing connections even though they should be closed?

My code

```
Private Sub PivotAccessADODB()
' Link Pivottable to access database

Const ConnectionPath As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\name\Desktop\DataBase.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"


    Dim DataConnection As ADODB.Connection: Set DataConnection = New ADODB.Connection
    Dim RecordSet As ADODB.RecordSet: Set RecordSet = New ADODB.RecordSet

    DataConnection.ConnectionString = ConnectionPath
    DataConnection.Open

    Dim SQLString As String: SQLString = "SELECT * FROM ALFA"

    With RecordSet
        .ActiveConnection = DataConnection
        .Source = SQLString
        .LockType = adLockReadOnly
        .CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
        .Open
    End With

' Initiate accept of external data
Dim PTCache As PivotCache

Set PTCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlExternal)
Set PTCache.RecordSet = RecordSet

Dim PT As PivotTable: Set PT = PTCache.CreatePivotTable(Worksheets("Pivot").Range("A1"), "Test")

'Cleanup
RecordSet.Close: Set RecordSet = Nothing
DataConnection.Close: Set DataConnection = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

The connection doesn't close because it is referenced, indirectly, by the pivot table. Using an idiom like the one below avoids this problem:

```
Private Function executeQuery(sqlStatement) As ADODB.recordSet
    'where conn is a global ADODB.Connection object
    Set executeQuery = conn.Execute(sqlStatement, RecordsAffected:=0)
End Function

Private Sub displayResultsFor(rs As recordSet, target As Range)
    writeHeader rs, target
    writeBody rs, target
End Sub

Private Sub writeHeader(rs As ADODB.recordSet, target As Range)
     Dim header As Range
     Dim i As Integer

     Set header = target
     For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        header.value = rs.Fields(i).name
        Set header = header.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1)
     Next i
End Sub

Private Sub writeBody(rs As ADODB.recordSet, target)
    target.Offset(RowOffset:=1).CopyFromRecordset rs
End Sub
```

This will display the contents of the recordset and avoid the pivottable and thereby avoid the stored connection. This may or may not be what you want. The other option that you have is write a bit of code to delete the connection. The downside of that is that you will no longer be able to use

```
pt.RefreshTable
```

Comment: Hmmm, what I don't get in this case is even though using my current solution with referenced connection, I still can't refresh the pivottable ( the option is darkened out when right-clicking on the pivot-table ). I have no issues with having a connection open, but now I don't have any use of it as I can't refresh and I would like the connection to close when I delete the pivottable, which does not seem to happen either.

Comment: You're right. I can't seem to update the pivot table manually, although doing it programmatically works just fine. To be honest I am a bit stumped why this should be the case. You could use some event based code as a workaround or add a button somewhere to update the table.